# How to execute only image build with spring boot maven plugin

Tags: spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot 2.5.x and I create the docker image with the following command

```
./mvnw spring-boot:build-image -Dspring-boot.build-image.imageName=myImage
```

The goal "build-image" seems execute the "verify" also.

Is it possible to execute only the build image without redoing the build of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to execute only the build image without redoing the build of the project?

Not currently, because `spring-boot:build-image` forks the Maven lifecycle to run the `package` phase. The design is discussed in a [Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/26455). There isn't a good solution yet to meeting the needs of both uses cases (the current use case of running `spring-boot:build-image` without requiring a jar to be built first, and the use case of not re-building when the jar is already built).